# How can I make a post request to check if the server is down from my app component in angular

Tags: angular, express

I want to write a function in my app component so that when I call it, it checks if the server is down

this is what my app components looks like

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
checking = this.callServer();
user1 = { id : 1, name : 'Hello'};

  callServer() {
     const headers = new HttpHeaders()
           .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
           .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/ping', JSON.stringify(this.user1), {
       headers: headers
     })
     .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
     });
}
}
```

and this is what the server.js look like in the back end

```
app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
    req.body.text = `${req.body.text} from Nodejs`;
    res.send(req.body);
}); 
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('server start on    port', port);
    expiration.get();
});
```

I provided the minimum code needed since it's in a big project, Feel free to ask for any additional info, there's no error in the back end but the function seems is not working!
I wouldn't mind any changes even if it's about a new method or function as long as it will help me complete this task

Comment: I think we need some more info. Here are few questions: Does the request reach the backend? Do you get any error in the browser console when you send the request? Have you tried using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" in the request url?

Comment: no the request doesn't reach the back end. I don't get an error related to that in the console and I tried localhost too

Comment: Could you please try replacing this: .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
     });

With this: 
.subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
This way a console error should appear with some details.